# Why does single threaded process change CPU

Tags: multithreading

I have single threaded PERL program running in Solaris. The thread number is confirmed by `prstat` command.

But `prstat` also suggests the the CPU the process is running is changing. Why?

```
PID USERNAME   SIZE   RSS STATE   PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP
9905 owngebsg 1004M  1003M cpu5    30    0   0:14:56 1.6% process_netstat/1
9905 owngebsg 1024M  1023M cpu4    20    0   0:15:13 1.6% process_netstat/1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating system schedules threads on different CPUs when its time slice expires. There is no guarantee a thread will be scheduled on the same CPU every time which is the case. Also the set of instructions of a thread can run on multiple CPUs but not at once. If you intention to run a thread on a dedicated CPU, you can do it via [taskset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following sequence of events on a 2-CPU machine:

- Process A runs on CPU1
- Process B runs on CPU2
- Process C preempts process A on CPU1
- Process B finishes

It makes sense for the scheduler to now run Process A on CPU2.

OS schedulers try to maximize (some notion of) fairness and system utilization. Keeping a process on one CPU is not a design goal of most schedulers. However, many OSes make it possible with some effort. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity.

Answer (score 0):

> But `prstat` also suggests the the CPU the process is running is changing. Why?

The scheduler can run your process on any available CPU, unless you constrain the set of CPUs your process is allowed to run on.